# Raw food veganism - maintaining energy levels as an older athlete

Tags: veganism, sports, aging, rawfood-diet

So about 15 years ago I was a raw food vegan and life was great, fast forward 15  years and I keep coming back to the idea of going back to raw food. I tend to skateboard every day and play rugby on the weekends with chasing a toddler in between.  My primary concern is energy levels and being able to keep up. I didn't have any issues with energy previously but that was also a long time ago.

Is there anything I maybe need to be taking or take into consideration before shifting back into raw foods that I'm currently missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Energy is usually not a concern since lots of fresh and sundried fruits have plenty of calories.

However, the word "energy" has also another meaning: "vitality". In other words, some lack of nutrients can make you feel weak and "without energy". It's definitely possible to have a complete and balanced diet with raw food. You should check whether you might be missing some important nutrient by doing some blood test. Have a check of blood iron and B12 (homocysteine, B12, folates). If you still feel weak and nothing comes up from blood test, ask a doctor.

Comment: I don't think OP is feeling weak or lacking vitality - they are just worried about the possibility? Maybe I misunderstand your wording. Also, B12 supplements are essential for all vegans I believe? PS, where do you manage to get detailed blood tests without seeing a doctor? Impossible in my country afaik!

Comment: Yeah I'm not feeling week I just worry that with all I do in the summer months that it could be an issue and I'd like to avoid it if possible but the B12 idea is a good one for sure!